# display two items in carousel slider flutter

Tags: flutter, dictionary, carousel

[two items at the same time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsiNG.png)

for now i`m passing my dummy data to carousel items.

showing two items at the same time in slider is what i aiming for...

but as you know map method traverse one item for the list at a time...

for now i divided carousel item by 2 with Row Widget...

is there any other way to accomplish?

something like increment to be increases 2 at a time for loop...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';

var reports = [
  {
    'title': '1',
    'content': '1'
  },
  {
    'title': '2',
    'content': '2'
  },
  {
    'title': '3',
    'content': '3'
  },
  {
    'title': '4',
    'content': '4'
  },
];

Widget buildReport() {
  return CarouselSlider(
    options: CarouselOptions(
      height: 250.0,
    ),
    items: reports
        .asMap()
        .map(
          (i, report) {
            return MapEntry(
              i,
              Builder(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Container(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        Card(
                          child: Container(
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  '${report['title']}',
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  '${report['content']}',
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),//i wish these two cards have different data.
                        Card(
                          child: Container(
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  '${report['title']}',
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  '${report['content']}',
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        )
        .values
        .toList(),
  );
}
```

and i thought about (for loop) but i don`t know how to do that in this code...

Comment: ㅠㅠ so sad...thank you

Answer (score 6):

try: viewportFraction: 0.5, that the container take 50% of screen

```
options: CarouselOptions(
      height: 250.0,
      viewportFraction: 0.5,
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key, this.choice, @required this.item}) : super(key: key);

  final Choice choice;
  final Choice item;

  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Basic demo')),
      body: Container(
          child: CarouselSlider(
        options: CarouselOptions(
          disableCenter: false,
        ),
        items: choices
            .map((Choice) => Container(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
                      Card(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                Choice.title,
                                style: null,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                Choice.content,
                                style: null,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Card(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                Choice.title,
                                style: null,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                Choice.content,
                                style: null,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  color: Colors.green,
                ))
            .toList(),
      )),
    ));
  }
}

class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.content});

  final String title;

  final String content;
}

const List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
  const Choice(title: 'title : 1', content: 'content : 1'),
  const Choice(title: 'title : 2', content: 'content : 2'),
  const Choice(title: 'title : 3', content: 'content : 3'),
  const Choice(title: 'title : 4', content: 'content : 4'),
];
```